# Generate Migration in Yii2

Tags: yii2, migration

I create Migration File in Yii2 using this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html
but it takes many time , any easy way to create schema in Yii2?

Comment: My friend created an extension for doing this: [Yii2 Migrations](/opt/icu5c-51_2), check this.

Comment: your link is not valid

Comment: @Yupik can you please provide me that extension link ?? i want to create migration file automatically.

Comment: My bad, here you go [Yii2 Migrations](https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration), @scaisEdge thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension [yii2-migration](https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration).
This extension generates migration file based on the existing database table and previous migrations.